# Jenkins slave slower than jenkins master

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins master x which is also the slave of Jenkins master Y. A job that runs in 15 mins on Jenkins master x, takes one hour to complete on Jenkins slave x.

Any explanation anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many possible reasons for that:

- different **workspace locations** (local vs. network storage)
- **massive slave/master communication** for "Slave x" case, e.g. caused by

  - lots of **console output**
  - storing huge amounts of **artifact data** (will pass from slave *via master* to storage)
- different **JVM settings** for Slave x and Master x

Otherwise, you will need to monitor in detail.

Comment: on monitoring, i found that the archiving was the issue* sending data from slave to master to archive). Thanks !